# syntax error, unexpected identifier "header", expecting ")"

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

I was trying to use DataTables and add a line of code in blade

before

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <title>ChatBot</title>
      <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico" />
      <link href="{{ asset('css/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
      <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/customtemplate.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "botwidget/css/materialize.min.css">
      <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "botwidget/css/style.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

      @yield('header')
   </head>
```

now I tried to add a line of code

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/dataTables.min.css) }}">
```

then came this error
Is there a problem in the line of code?

I also tried to add a line of js

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/dataTable.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Will it also Problem cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the simple closing quote in your CSS asset file path, it should look like the one below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/dataTables.min.css') }}">
```